# Android ndk file not found on github actions

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, github-actions

I am trying to implement CI on app which contains native code in C++ using github actions
When i am running workflow it's says that there is no headers near the .cpp, but it is here and i have setted include directories in build.gradle and Android.mk file, the build is fine on local PC(windows)

> [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: samp <= CAuthentication.cpp In file
> included from
> /home/runner/work/client/client/app/src/main/cpp/CAuthentication.cpp:3:
> /home/runner/work/client/client/app/src/main/cpp/main.h:23:10: fatal
> error: 'vendor\RakNet\SAMP\samp_netencr.h' file not found
> #include "vendor\RakNet\SAMP\samp_netencr.h"

file CAuthentication.cpp is in the same directory as directory "vendor"

I also tried to set environment variable in github job but it does not help

Comment: Don't use `>\<` as a path separator. This is the escape character. Use `>/<`. Note: ignore the characters `><` had to add them to stop the escape escaping the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using backslashes in your include directives as the error seems to suggest, try to change them into forward slashes:

```cpp
#include "vendor/RakNet/SAMP/samp_netencr.h"
```

Also check the path for case correctness. Windows has a case-insensitive filesystem, while the CI might be running some form of Linux.